# Massless Dirac Field Chirality and CP

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, chirality

I have some very basic questions about Quantum Field Theory. So let's assume we have massless fermions. In 4 spacetime dimensions, due to the Group Structure of $SO(3,1)$ there exists the famous $\gamma_5$ matrix which can be used to reduce any representation of the group to the so--called *left-handed* and *right-handed* parts. As far as I understand the eigenvalues of $\gamma_5$ are good quantum numbers for massless fermions; much in the same way that charge is - for a theory satisfying global gauge invariance.

Now to the point: Weinberg, in his extremely lucid presentation of Quantum Field Theory, argues that the fields in order to conserve quantum numbers, should be consisted of creation operators of particle *and* annihilation operators for antiparticle. In particular

> The Dirac field $\psi (x)$ for massless fermions, should *create* particles of charge $Q=+1$ and *destroy* antiparticles of charge $Q = -1$, so that global charge conservation is maintained.

As far as I understand; the field

> $\psi_L (x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left( 1 - \gamma_5 \right)\psi (x)$ (assuming it is charged) should:
>   create *left-handed* particles of charge $Q=+1$ *and* annihilate *right-handed* antiparticles of charge $Q=-1$, so that both chirality (eigenvalue of $\gamma_5$) and charge are globally conserved.

Similarly:

> $\psi_R (x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left( 1 + \gamma_5 \right)\psi (x)$ (assuming it is charged) should:
>   create *right-handed* particles of charge $Q=+1$ *and* annihilate *left-handed* antiparticles of charge $Q=-1$, so that both chirality (eigenvalue of $\gamma_5$) and charge are globally conserved.

Now $SO(3,1)$ has an invariant tensor which acts as $CP$. I want to understand first of all if the above description of the field is correct, and second of all what would the effect of $CP$ be on say $\psi$, $\psi_{L,R}$.